# Chain function on array.flat() not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why chaining function on array.flat not working as expected

```
const input = [[[{"type":"banana"},{"type":"orange"}]]];

console.log(input.flat(2).push({"type":"grapes"}));
```

What I expect is, it should remove the 2 array wrapper and push a new item to `input`

But I get only the `length` why is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array.

You could concat the array ([`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)) with a new element and get the new array.

```
console.log(input.flat(2).concat({ type: "grapes" }));
```

Comment: What If I need to add the grapes as first item? how does unshift works with concat ?

Comment: `unshift` returns the new length, as `push`, because it's the other side of the same action. but you could switch the flat part and the concat: `[{ type: "grapes" }].concat(input.flat(2))`

Comment: hi @Nina Scholz could you please try to answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334074/creating-new-data-object-set-from-multiple-nested-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Array.push mutates the array itself and returns only the length of the array. You can log the array in the next line after the push statement.

Answer (score 0):

The [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method returns the new length of the array and mutates it.

Try instead:

```js
const input = [[[{"type":"banana"},{"type":"orange"}]]];
const flattened = input.flat(2)
flattened.push({"type":"grapes"});
console.log(flattened) 
/* 
  [
    {type:"banana"},
    {type:"orange"},
    {type:"grapes"}
  ] 
*/
```

Comment: `flat()` does not mutate the original array. So you have to store the returned array in another variable before using `push()` or you will lost it. I believe you wanted to write: `let flattenArr = input.flat(2); flattenArr.push(...); console.log(flattenArr);`

Comment: @Shidersz Thanks, I haven't noticed this, and I've corrected it now :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also other than [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) also spread into a new array to achieve the same result:

```js
const input = [[[{"type":"banana"},{"type":"orange"}]]];

console.log([...input.flat(2), {"type":"grapes"}]);
```

The issue in your code however is that [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) returns a whole new array for you to work with and [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) simply returns the new length of the array (**so you need to keep a reference to the array**). So with some refactoring:

```js
const input = [[[{"type":"banana"},{"type":"orange"}]]];

let newArr = input.flat(2)  // <-- this would return a new array

newArr.push({"type":"grapes"})  // We do not care what push returns since we have a reference to the array

console.log(newArr)
```

You get the expected result

Also note of caution with `Array.flatMap` and `Array.flat` ... both **do not have support in IE** and you would need a polyfill