# Creating new data object set from multiple nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I've have a complex data structure with multiple nested arrays in place.

Below is the current structure

```
var contentData = {
  data: {
    content: [
      {
        type: "column",
        sections: [
          {
            sub: [
              {
                type: "heading-1",
                text: "Heading Text"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "acc-item",
        sections: [
          {
            sub: [
              {
                type: "heading-1",
                text: "Heading Text"
              },
              {
                type: "ordered-item",
                text: "Item 1"
              },
              {
                type: "unordered-item",
                text: "Item 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "acc-item",
        sections: [
          {
            sub: [
              {
                type: "heading-1",
                text: "Heading Text 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So What I wanted is,

1. I wanted to group all the `ordered-item & unordered-item` into a new object like `{type: 'list', items:[all list items]}`.
2. I need to extract all items which are inside `sub` and push it to new object `embedded` and it should placed in the root level like below,

   `{type:"acc-item",embedded:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text 2"}]};`

So What I've done so far,

I can able to group `acc-item`, but not the `ordered-item & unordered-item`.

So my final expected result should like this,

```
[{
  "type": "column",
  "embedded": [
    {
      "type": "heading-1",
      "text": "Heading Text"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "acc-group",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "acc-item",
      "embedded": [
        {
          "type": "heading-1",
          "text": "Heading Text"
        },
        {
          "type": "list",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "ordered-item",
              "text": "Item 1"
            },
            {
              "type": "unordered-item",
              "text": "Item 2" 
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "acc-item",
      "embedded": [
        {
          "type": "heading-1",
          "text": "Heading Text 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

Below is my code,

```js
var group,contentData={data:{content:[{type:"column",sections:[{sub:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text"}]}]},{type:"acc-item",sections:[{sub:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text"},{type:"ordered-item",text:"Item 1"},{type:"unordered-item",text:"Item 2"}]}]},{type:"acc-item",sections:[{sub:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text 2"}]}]}]}},types=[["list",["ordered-item","unordered-item"]],["accordion",["acc-item"]]];

var result = contentData.data.content.reduce((r, o) => {
  var type = (types.find(({ 1: values }) => values.indexOf(o.type) > -1)|| {})[0];
  if (!type) {
    r.push(o);
    group = undefined;
    return r;
  }
  if (!group || group.type !== type) {
    group = { type, items: [] };
    r.push(group);
  }
  group.items.push(o);
  return r;
}, []);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, '  ') + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the last items array as well as the last embedded array and use them until a column type is found.

```js
var contentData = { data: { content: [{ type: "column", sections: [{ sub: [{ type: "heading-1", text: "Heading Text" }] }] }, { type: "acc-item", sections: [{ sub: [{ type: "heading-1", text: "Heading Text" }, { type: "ordered-item", text: "Item 1" }, { type: "unordered-item", text: "Item 2" }] }] }, { type: "acc-item", sections: [{ sub: [{ type: "heading-1", text: "Heading Text 2" }] }] }] } },
    list = ["ordered-item", "unordered-item"],
    lastItems, lastEmbedded,
    result = contentData.data.content.reduce((r, { type, sections }) => {
        if (type === 'column') {
            r.push({ type, embedded: sections.reduce((q, { sub }) => q.concat(sub), []) });
            lastItems = undefined;
            lastEmbedded = undefined;
            return r;
        }
        if (!lastItems) r.push({ type: "acc-group", items: lastItems = [] });
        lastItems.push(...sections.map(({ sub }) => ({
            type,
            embedded: sub.reduce((q, o) => {
                if (list.includes(o.type)) {
                    if (!lastEmbedded) q.push({ type: 'list', items: lastEmbedded = [] });
                    lastEmbedded.push(o);
                } else {
                    q.push(o);
                    lastEmbedded = undefined;
                }
                return q;
            }, [])
        })));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: one issue, `"ordered-item", "unordered-item"` is not grouping inside columns

Comment: Can you use this  `var contentData={data:{content:[{type:"column",sections:[{sub:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text"},{type:"ordered-item",text:"Item 1"},{type:"unordered-item",text:"Item 2"}]}]},{type:"acc-item",sections:[{sub:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text"},{type:"ordered-item",text:"Item 1"},{type:"unordered-item",text:"Item 2"}]}]},{type:"acc-item",sections:[{sub:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text 2"}]}]},{type:"column",sections:[{sub:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text"},{type:"ordered-item",text:"Item 1"},{type:"unordered-item",text:"Item 2"}]}]}]}};`

Comment: how shold look this as result?

Comment: list is not grouping inside column, so expected result `[{type:"column",embedded:[{type:"heading-1",text:"Heading Text"},{type:"list",items:[{type:"ordered-item",text:"Item 1"},{type:"unordered-item",text:"Item 2"}]}]}];`

Answer (score 0):

The [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) and [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) methods are perfect for this kind of thing.

And you're right that this is some complicated kind of logic.

I would suggest that you definitely need some unit tests for this, and try break in to separate pieces.

Here's how I'm thinking I'd do it.

**1. Group By the type to create your groups.**.

I'm actually creating a more generic solution that you've asked for here. That is,  I'm not just grouping the 'acc-item', but everything.

I did a quick search for 'array group by javascript' and it gives us [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects) which suggests using Array.reduce, so let's do that.

```
    const groupedData = contentData.data.content.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        //Check if this indexed array already exists, if not create it. 
        const currentArray = (acc[`${cur.type}-group`] && acc[`${cur.type}-group`].items) || [];

        return {
          ...acc,
          [`${cur.type}-group`]: {
              type: `${cur.type}-group`, 
              items: [...currentArray, cur]
          }
        }
    }, {});
```

**2. Now for each of those items, we need to look at their subs, and group just the list items.**

To do this, we basically want to find all the `item -> sections -> sub -> types and filter them into two arrays. A quick google on how to create two arrays using a filter gives me [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731072/dividing-an-array-by-filter-function)

First though, we need to flatten that sections-> subs thing, so lets just do that.

```
function flattenSectionsAndSubs(item) {
    return {
        type: item.type, 
        subs: item.sections.reduce((acc, cur) => ([...acc, ...cur.sub]), [])
    }; 
}
```

And I'll just copy paste that partition function in:

```
function partition(array, isValid) {
  return array.reduce(([pass, fail], elem) => {
    return isValid(elem) ? [[...pass, elem], fail] : [pass, [...fail, elem]];
  }, [[], []]);
}


    const listTypes = ['ordered-item', 'unordered-item']; 
    function createEmbeddedFromItem(item) {
        const [lists, nonLists] = partition(item.subs, (v) => listTypes.includes(v.type); 

      return {
         type: item.type, 
         embedded: [
             ...nonLists, 
             {
                type: "list", 
                items: lists
             }
         ]
      }
    }
```

**Putting this all together and we get.**

```js
const contentData = {
  data: {
    content: [{
        type: "column",
        sections: [{
          sub: [{
            type: "heading-1",
            text: "Heading Text"
          }]
        }]
      },
      {
        type: "acc-item",
        sections: [{
          sub: [{
              type: "heading-1",
              text: "Heading Text"
            },
            {
              type: "ordered-item",
              text: "Item 1"
            },
            {
              type: "unordered-item",
              text: "Item 2"
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        type: "acc-item",
        sections: [{
          sub: [{
            type: "heading-1",
            text: "Heading Text 2"
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}


function partition(array, isValid) {
  return array.reduce(([pass, fail], elem) => {
    return isValid(elem) ? [
      [...pass, elem], fail
    ] : [pass, [...fail, elem]];
  }, [
    [],
    []
  ]);
}


function flattenSectionsAndSubs(item) {
  return {
    type: item.type,
    subs: item.sections.reduce((acc, cur) => ([...acc, ...cur.sub]), [])
  };
}

const listTypes = ['ordered-item', 'unordered-item'];

function createEmbeddedFromItem(item) {
  const [lists, nonLists] = partition(item.subs, (v) => listTypes.includes(v.type));

    return {
      type: item.type,
      embedded: [
        ...nonLists,
        {
          type: "list",
          items: lists
        }
      ]
    }
  }


  const groupedData = contentData.data.content.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    //Check if this indexed array already exists, if not create it. 
    const currentArray = (acc[`${cur.type}-group`] && acc[`${cur.type}-group`].items) || [];

    const flattenedItem = flattenSectionsAndSubs(cur);
    const embeddedItem = createEmbeddedFromItem(flattenedItem);
    return {
      ...acc,
      [`${cur.type}-group`]: {
          type: `${cur.type}-group`, 
          items: [...currentArray, embeddedItem]
      }
    }
  }, {});

  console.log(groupedData);
```

Now this doesn't exactly match what you've asked for - but it should probably work.

You can add your own bits into only add a list item, if the array isn't empty, and to stop the column from being in its own group.

The thing is - tbh it seems like a little bit of a red flag that you would create an array of items that don't having matching structures, which is why I've done it this way.

Comment: in `flattenSectionsAndSubs` .flat dosent work in IE

Comment: See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696119/es6-spread-syntax-ie-not-supported

You might want to use a polyfill, or use babel to compile your production code, or change the syntax slightly.

Comment: I've copied the code here, so that it's compiled with babel - see that it works there: https://codepen.io/dwjohnston/pen/KLBwza?editors=1111

Comment: I could see a empty `list` getting added in the result

Comment: @user007 yes. See my final comments. You can edit the code yourself to get this to do exactly what you want. I've shown you the general process.